# Does a completely metrizable space admit a compatible metric where all intersections of nested closed balls are non-empty?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

(cross-posted from [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679118/does-a-completely-metrizable-space-admit-a-compatible-metric-where-all-intersect))

It is well-known that given a metric space $(X,d)$, the metric is complete if and only if every intersection of nested (i.e. decreasing with respect to inclusion) closed balls of vanishing diameters have non-empty intersection. This is usually referred to as Cantor's Intersection Theorem.

*Is it true that every completely **metrizable** topological space **admits one compatible metric** such that every intersection of nested closed balls has a non-empty intersection?*

---

### Some more details:

Let's call spherically complete a metric as above where every intersection of nested closed balls has non-empty intersection.

Not every complete metric is spherically complete (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314912/in-a-metric-space-the-intersection-of-nested-closed-balls-is-empty) and the list of its related questions).

However, this question is not about a fixed metric, but about the existence of one metric compatible with the topology.

We know there exist (classes of) completely metrizable spaces that admit compatible spherically complete metrics.

For example:

- All (complete) metrics on a compact space are spherically complete.
- The standard euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is spherically complete.
- All completely ultrametrizable spaces admit a compatible spherically complete metric.

So to be more precise my question is:

- Do all completely metrizable topological spaces admit a compatible spherically complete metric?
- If not, is it known what is the largest class of (completely metrizable) topological spaces that admit one?

I suspect that every locally compact completely metrizable space admits a spherically complete metric, and probably the same is true for Polish spaces (using that they are homeomorphic to $G_\delta$ subsets of the Hilbert cube).
But I could not find any reference for this.

Comment: For any set $X$, the metric $d$ defined by $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise is spherically complete, and it gives the discrete topology (the only closed balls are points and $X$ itself).

Comment: Ok, that was a silly doubt.. so with the delta, all closed balls are either singletons or the whole space :)

Comment: A metric space is completely metrizable if and only if it is a $G_\delta$ subspace of its Cauchy completion. The usual proof of the "if" direction gives you an actual formula for a complete metric $\delta$ on $X$ in terms of a complete metric $d$ on its completion: $$\delta(x,y) = d(x,y) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{| d(x,U_n)^{-1} -  d(y,U_n)^{-1}|}{1+| d(x,U_n)^{-1} -  d(y,U_n)^{-1}|},$$ where $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$ are open and $X = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$. I've stared at this formula for the last few minutes, and I can't decide whether it's spherically complete or not. But maybe?

Comment: It seems to me that another example  of “spherically complete” is any Banach space. Indeed, for balls in a normed space, $B(x’,r’)\subset B(x,r)$ implies $\|x-x’\|\le r-r’$ (looking at the line between $x$ and $x’$). So for a nested family of closed balls $\bar B(x_k,r_k)$  the sequence of the centers is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Nevermind -- the formula in my previous comment need not be spherically complete. For example, if $d$ is a complete but not spherically complete metric on $X$, then the formula just gives $\delta = d$.

Comment: @WillBrian true, but I think that your comment still gives a useful hint on a way to approach the problem: with that formula, one could maybe prove that any $G_\delta$-subspace of a *spherically complete* metric space is again metrizable with a spherically complete metric. Then if we show that any metrizable space is a subspace of a "completion" admitting a spherically complete metric, we would be done?

Comment: @Cla: That's not a bad idea. Every metrizable space embeds into a countable product of "hedgehogs" (where a "hedgehog" means the 1-point compactification of a bunch of copies of $[0,1)$). Maybe it's not too hard to find a spherically complete metric on these universal spaces.

Comment: Is it possible to find a spherically complete metric on the irrationals?

Comment: Every locally compact separable metrizable space admits a proper  metric (i.e. a metric, under which closed balls are compact, sometimes also called Heine-Borel  metric.) This one is surely spherically complete.

Comment: @BenjaminVejnar And without assuming separability? Does a locally compact metrisable space always admit a metric for which at least all closed *unit* balls are compact? I would say yes (even if it is not separable)

Comment: (This would imply that locally compact metrisable spaces admits a spherically complete metric, without assuming separability)

Comment: @PietroMajer On one hand side: proper metric spaces are separable, since these are countable unions of compact metric spaces (n-balls). On the other hand, I believe that every locally compact metrizable space admits a metric whose unit balls are compact (through paracompactness of a metrizable space and partition of unity).

Comment: Exact; and it seems to me one can make such a metric $d$ even without using paracompactness. Then if one truncates this metric defining $d':=\min\{d, 1\}$, the closed balls of $d'$ are either compact balls of $d$, or the whole $X$, so that $d'$ is spherically complete.

Comment: Every Polish space is (up to a homeomorphism) a closed subset of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Is this space spherically complete?

Comment: @BenjaminVejnar yes, I believe so. The standard metric should be spherically complete

Comment: More generally, any complete metric space $X$ embeds isometrically as a closed subspace of the Banach space (thus Sph. Com.) $( C_b(X),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$  of bounded continuous functions on $X$.

Comment: @PietroMajer Is every closed convex subset $C$ of a Banach space spherically complete?

Comment: Good question! It did not seem obvious.

Comment: A condition that implies sph. compl. for a complete metric space $X$ is: for all $x\in X$ and $y\in X$ and $r>0$, there exists $z\in X$ such that $d(y,z)=r$ and $d(x,y)+d(y,z)=d(x,z).$ It's quite strong: it implies that decreasing nested sequences of closed balls have decreasing radii; are a Cauchy sequence of closed sets w.r.to the Hausdorff metric, and their centres are a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @PietroMajer Your condition is the Axiom of Segment Construction, well-known in Foundations of Geometry.

Comment: What I do not see clearly and would like to know are the implications in the other direction: What are the consequences of being spherically complete, for a metric space (besides standard completeness of course)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any topological property that holds for all spherically completely metrizable spaces, but not necessarily for all completely metrizable spaces (which is the reason why I was hoping that the two notions were the same).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us say that a topological space $X$ is *spherically completely metrizable* if the topology of $X$ is generated by a spherically complete metric.

> **Theorem.**  Every closed subspace $X$ of the countable product of locally compact metrizable spaces is spherically completely metrizable.

*Proof.* We lose no generality assuming that $X$ is a closed subspace of the countable power $L^\omega$ of some locally compact metrizable space $L$. By the paracompactness, the locally compact metrizable space $L$ is a topological sum $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\kappa}L_\alpha$ of clopen $\sigma$-compact subspaces. Each space $L_\alpha$ is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact, and hence its topology is generated by a metric $d_\alpha$ whose closed balls are compact. On the space $L$ consider the metric $d$ defined by
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{if $x\in L_\alpha$ and $y\in L_\beta$ for distinct $\alpha,\beta\in\kappa$};\\
\min\{d_\alpha(x,y),1\}&\mbox{if $x,y\in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\kappa$}.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that for every $c\in L$ and every $r<1$ the closed ball $B_L(c;r):=\{x\in L:d(x,c)\le r\}$ is compact and for every $r\ge 1$, $B_L(c;r)=L$.

On the countable power $L^\omega$ consider the complete metric $\rho$ defined by $$\rho((x_n)_{n\in\omega},(y_n)_{n\in\omega})=\max_{n\in\omega}\frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}.$$

We claim that the metric $\rho$ induces a spherically complete metric on the closed subspace $X\subseteq L^\omega$.

Let $(B_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be a sequence of nested closed balls in $X$. Let $(c_n)_{n\in\omega}$ and $(r_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be the sequences of the centers and radii of the balls $B_n$. Since every sequence of positive real numbers contains a monotone subsequence, we lose no generality assuming that the sequence $(r_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is monotone.

If the sequence $(r_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is increasing (i.e., $r_n\le r_{n+1}$ for all $n$), then for every $n\in\omega$ we have $c_n\in B_n\subseteq B_0$ and hence $\rho(c_n,c_0)\le r_0\le r_n$ and $c_0\in B(c_n;r_n)=B_n$.

So, we assume that $(r_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is strictly decreasing.

If $\inf_{n\in\omega}r_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=0$ and the intersection $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}B_n$ is not empty by the completeness of the metric $\rho$.

So, we assume that $r:=\inf_{ n\in\omega}r_n>0$.

If $r\ge 1$, then every ball $B_n$ coincides with $X$ and hence $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}B_n=X\ne\emptyset$.

So, we assume that $r<1$. Let $m\in\omega$ be the largest number such that $2^m r<1$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=r$, we can replace the sequence $(B_n)_{n\in\omega}$ by a suitable subsequence, and assume that $2^mr_0<1$. Then for every $k\in\omega$, the ball $B_L(c_0(k),2^mr_0)$ in $L$ is compact. For every $n\in\omega$, the inclusion $c_n\in B_n\subseteq B_0$ implies $\rho(c_n,c_0)\le r_0$ and hence $d(c_n(k),c_0(k))\le 2^kr_0$. Then for every $k\le m$, the sequence $(c_n(k))_{n\in\omega}$ is contained in the compact ball $B_L(c_0(k),2^mr_0)$ and hence has a convergent subsequence.

Replacing $(B_n)_{n\in\omega}$ by a suitable subsequence, we can assume that for every $k\le m$ the sequence $(c_n(k))_{n\in\omega}$ is convergent in $L$, and moreover $d(c_i(k),c_j(k))<r$ for all $i,j\in\omega$.

We claim that $\rho(c_0,c_n)\le r_n$ for every $n\in\omega$. This inequality will follow as soon as we check that $d(c_0(k),c_n(k))\le 2^kr_n$ for all $k\in\omega$.

If $k>m$, then $d(c_0(k),c_n(k))\le 1\le 2^{m+1}r<2^kr_n$ by the definition of the metric $d$.

If $k\le m$, then $d(c_0(k),c_n(k))<r\le 2^kr_n$ by the choice of the (sub)sequence $(B_i)_{i\in\omega}$.

Therefore, $c_0\in \bigcap_{n\in\omega}B_n$. $\quad\square$.

Since every Polish space is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega$, Theorem implies

> **Corollary.** Every Polish space is spherically completely metrizable.

The Theorem suggests the following

> **Question.** Which metrizable spaces do embed into countable products of locally compact metrizable spaces?

**Remark 1.** The necessary condition of the embeddability of a topological space $X$ into the countable product of locally compact metrizable spaces is the separability of all quasicomponents of $X$. This condition implies that nonseparable connected metrizable spaces do not embed into countable products of locally compact metrizable spaces.

The following proposition answers the above Question.

> **Proposition.** A topological space $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the countable product of locally compact metrizable spaces if and only if $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa^\omega$ for some cardinal $\kappa$ endowed with the discrete topology.

*Proof.* The "if" part of this characterization is trivial. To prove the "only if" part, assume that $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the product $\prod_{n\in\omega}L_n$ of locally compact metrizable spaces $L_n$. By the paracompactness, every space $L_\alpha$ is a topological sum of locally compact $\sigma$-compact metrizable spaces and hence is a topological sum of Polish spaces. Since every Polish space is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the space $\mathbb R^\omega$, for every $n\in\omega$ the locally compact metrizable space $L_n$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$. Then $\prod_{n\in\omega}L_n$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the space $(\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa)^\omega$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa^\omega$. $\quad\square$

Proposition and Theorem imply that every closed subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa^\omega$ is spherically completely metrizable.

> **Problem.** Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. Is every closed metrizable subspace of the space $[0,1]^\kappa\times\kappa^\omega$ spherically completely metrizable?

**Remark 2.** For every cardinal $\kappa$, every closed metrizable subspace of the space $[0,1]^\kappa\times\kappa^\omega$ is completely metrizable. On the other hand, closed metrizable subspaces of the space $\mathbb R^\kappa$ are realcompact but needs not be completely metrizable (by Theorem 3.11.12 in Engelking's "General Topology", every Lindelof space is realcompact; in particluar, every metrizable separable space is realcompact).

Comment: Thanks, that gives excellent sufficient conditions. It is maybe worth noticing that a space is completely ultrametrizable if and only if it is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\kappa^\omega$ for some $\kappa$, so your proposition gives also a proper extension of what was known for ultrametrizable spaces.

Comment: Also, the [radial metric on the plane](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000134/properties) is an example of a non-separable connected spherically complete metric space, that thus does not embed into $\mathbb{R}^\omega\times \kappa^\omega$, so this condition is not necessary.

Comment: @Cla As was observed by Pietro Mayer, Banach spaces are spherically complete  and they also do not embed into $\mathbb R^\omega\times\kappa^\omega$. More generally, every complete metric space $(X,d)$ satisfying the Axiom of Segment Construction ($\forall x,y,a,b\in X\; \exists z\in X\; (d(y,z)=d(a,b) \wedge d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z))$) is spherically complete.